# New question frequency graphs

Tags: feature-request

I would like to be able to see:

1. a bar graph of number of new questions entered vs both time of day and day of week.

I think it would be interesting verify my suspicion that very few new questions get added on a Friday night.
I also would like to see:

1. a similar graph showing the number of questions that wind up getting closed vs both time of day and day of week that they were entered

This would help to answer the question, are there particular times of day or days of week when poor questions are most often entered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dunno about generating graphs—you may have to fire up Google Docs or Excel—but you can get the raw data you are looking for from the [Stack Exchange data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/english/queries):

I wrote a query that gets approximately the data you want:

http://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/63660/questions-by-time-of-day-and-day-of-week

Comment: thank you. I'll have a look.

Comment: Data Explorer is very cool.  I did not know about it.  Thank you!